# Canvas.js not displaying column for small values in column chart

Tags: jquery, css, html, canvas

I have created [**`fiddle`**](https://jsfiddle.net/nikhil72558/0yrpgpqe/) which creates column chart using `canvas.js` plugin. But for small values, it is not displaying column. In the example, a small value is 1 and `canvas.js` is not showing a column for this, the only label is visible.

See a Demo below

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  title: {
    text: "Column not visible for value 1"
  },
  data: [{
    type: "column",
    dataPoints: [{
        y: 1,
        indexLabel: "{y}"
      },
      {
        y: 55,
        indexLabel: "{y}"
      },
      {
        y: 50,
        indexLabel: "{y}"
      },
      {
        y: 65,
        indexLabel: "{y}"
      },
      {
        y: 95,
        indexLabel: "{y}"
      },
      {
        y: 68,
        indexLabel: "{y}"
      },
      {
        y: 28,
        indexLabel: "{y}"
      },
      {
        y: 600,
        indexLabel: "{y}"
      },
      {
        y: 14,
        indexLabel: "{y}"
      }
    ]
  }]
});
chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 360px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that a value of 1 is smaller than 1 pixel of the chart, so it just displays nothing. If you just want it to be one pixel high, you can set the value of that column higher and change the `indexLabel` to just read 1, like so:

```
{ y: 2,indexLabel: "1"},
```

That works if you're manually creating the chart, but if your chart is generated by some other bit of code, you might want to figure out what value corresponds to one pixel of the chart and write a handler for the case where the value of the column is smaller than that amount.